Building a Discrete Kalman Filter Model for Indirect Temperature Measurement
I need to implement Kalman filter to measure temperature of a toroid body at a temperature T2, where the temperature sensor is inside the toroid at a temperature T1. The T1 and T2 are related as
m * c * dT1/dt = k (T2 - T1)
where m, c and k are mass, specific heat and thermal conductivity respectively, or we can combine the constants all together to get
dT1/dt = alpha * (T2 - T1)
There is also another indirect measurement for T2, which is related to temperature as
T2 = beta * g + C
where g is a measured quantity, and this is not a very accurate measurement compared to the temperature sensor for measuring T1, and C is an another constant.
I need to make a the state space equation for this system then a Kalman filter to estimate T2. I can empirically found values for alpha and beta, however this expected to change one system to another. So, How do we design a Kalman filter for this situation.

Defining the state vector as:
$$ \boldsymbol{x} = \begin{bmatrix} {T}_{1} \\ {T}_{2} \\ g \\ C \end{bmatrix} $$
Then the continuous model:
$$ \dot{\boldsymbol{x}} = \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x}, \; \boldsymbol{A} = \begin{bmatrix} -\alpha & \alpha & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$
To generate the discrete model matrix $\boldsymbol{F}$ one must calculate the matrix exponent:
$$\boldsymbol{F} = {e}^{\boldsymbol{A} \Delta t } = \boldsymbol{I} + \boldsymbol{A} \Delta t + \frac{1}{2!} \boldsymbol{A}^{2} \Delta t + \ldots$$
If we take the 2 first terms to approximate the result:
$$\boldsymbol{F} \approx \boldsymbol{I} + \boldsymbol{A} \Delta t = \begin{bmatrix} 1 - \alpha \Delta t & \alpha \Delta t & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
The above state vector also gives:
$$ \boldsymbol{z} = \boldsymbol{H} \boldsymbol{x} $$
Where $\boldsymbol{H} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & \beta & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.
Given those 2 matrices you may run Kalman Filter as defined in Wikipedia - Kalman Filter.
Remarks:

It would improve the model greatly if you find a connection to the derivative of ${T}_{2}$ as well.
For better precision, take more terms from the matrix exponential series.

